# Ubuntu Grub problem

Tags: ubuntu, grub, reinstall

I have/(had) Windows XP on one partition of my hdd.  On the second partition I installed Ubuntu 9.10 yesterday.  After reboot of Windows XP, I get the error "GRUB LOADING.".

Now I know that you can play around with that using live Grub and all.  Putting Grub on top of MBR or etc etc. something like that.

I want to know - if I reinstall Ubuntu 10.04 which is available now - will it give me still the same error?  Or will I be able to use both OS?  (Ie, is that problem solved in version 10.04 or still there?  And if it is solved, will reinstalling Ubuntu solve the problem or not?)

Any help is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The new Ubuntu will install the latest GRUB2 and will rewrite the whole MBR/boot record , replacing the whole boot loader. SO, you will be able to boot (it is 99% likely that it will be possible, though there is always a slim chance that things will go FUBAR... we are talking about PCs.. :))
Even if it won't you can comment here from the newly installed Ubuntu and I'll (or we.. whatever ^^") help you out ASAP.
Here is a little trick what may work if you will fail to boot even after a new install. Do a FULL upgrade from System upgrade. Then open a terminal and type: `sudo update-grub2` . Say your prayers and reboot. :)
(For settings. Press alt+f2 and type: `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` There, you can see such lines like "timeout". You can edit things like that, but don't change what you don't know. Then do the same as above, sudo update-grub2.)